# Are numbers greater than one plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, numbers

Two apples **are** plural.

When I refer to a number of items only by their count, is the count singular?

For example: *"Two **is** enough."*

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking a this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+is+enough%2C+three+are+enough&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthree%20is%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%20are%20enough%3B%2Cc0), it seems that both *is* and *are* are valid.

[image: Google Ngram of "three is enough" vs "three are enough"]

And having a look through the excerpts from the books, I tend to agree that authors use either.

Some examples:

- "is enough"

> We use the pigeonhole principle to conclude that three is enough.

— [A Logical Approach to Discrete Math - Page 356](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZWTDQ6H6gsUC&pg=PA356&dq=%22three+is+enough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6GY3VeOdK831aoDagPgO&ved=0CCUQ6AEwATgK)

> Every one of my cymbals is also a crash cymhal. I only use three. Three is enough.

— [The Drummer's Time: Conversations with the Great Drummers of Jazz](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uHmDEwUmo_EC&pg=PA40&dq=%22three+is+enough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6GY3VeOdK831aoDagPgO&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAjgK)

> They say three is enough, thereby not attracting the folks from Chicago, Aurora, Fox River Valley.

— [The Quality Health-Care Coalition Act of 1998](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hDzccD0izDsC&q=%22three+is+enough%22&dq=%22three+is+enough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n2c3VcGOOZXtaMyhgKAP&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgU)

- "are enough"

> Or there may be four sisters, but three are enough to present the full range of good and evil.

— [Old Tales and New Truths: Charting the Bright-Shadow World](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xCiBOo4O5jcC&pg=PA29&dq=%22three+are+enough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xWU3Vfdmjt9q-M-AiA4&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22three%20are%20enough%22&f=false)

> Three are enough for most anything.

— [Yachting - Jan 1987 - Page 64](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kQiCtvcBLiwC&pg=PA64&dq=%22three+are+enough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iGg3VaKOJdLoaPqUgNAH&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ)

> The throat is the most common, and perilous, location for the hooks to hang up, because even two of the three are enough to block that passageway and doom the luckless gamefish to starvation.

— [Field & Stream - Mar 1989 - Page 68](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mMn9YCZ8HHgC&pg=PA68&dq=%22three+are+enough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iGg3VaKOJdLoaPqUgNAH&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCQ)

So, in conclusion, you can treat the bare number as either plural or singular.